# Following a Person In Real Time Using RFID

Tags: sensor, rfid, proximity-sensor

I am carrying out a project in which a trolley or carrier follows a person and follows him continuously wherever he moves inside a shopping complex or at airport.

I am confused whether to use RFID or some other technology which provides me identification of person and measuring of distance as I have mentioned. If I am able to get all requirements using RFID alone or by alternative method welcome. I am a completely newbie to RF area.

---

Comment: With usual RFID you can only detect if the person is within range or not. It's not easy to actually determine where the person is. You'd need to do triangulation using RFID to actually detect location and from what I see in your description, that probably won't be suitable.

Comment: RFID coupled with a PID for the motion control using the RSSI, would be a good approach.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I'd think a trio of directional arrays would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh From what I can see, OP wants to have the setup on a mobile platform. Wouldn't you need space between the arrays to work well? I fear that sufficient space would not be available on such a platform. It would probably be enough to determine which antenna is the closest, but to actually get position? I could see it working as a part of a larger system that wouldn't rely only on RFID, but then RFID solution loses its elegance.

Comment: Actually no, the system wouldn't need to know position, just direction - the distance:speed relationship would be provided by RSSI + PID. The same PID would correct for direction drift, so even direction precision is non-critical with suitable PID damping.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh Interesting idea! I'll have to think more about that topic then.

Comment: I'm imagining a shopping cart imitating a drunken sailor following a shopper around.

Comment: I would connect a cable between the trolley and person. Some sensors can detect whether there is tension in the cable (indicating that it is necessary to move) and which way the cable is being pulled to generate a correction of movement in that direction. Kind of like a doggy on a leash. The cable is an important security device: it provides feedback that the trolley is still there when the user isn't looking at it, maintains a maximum distance, and prevents people from combing between user and trolley.

Comment: Is it evident that OP has done any research?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this, so this is just thinking out loud, but I'd try coded IR first.  The person would wear a belt or something with IR LEDs are various angles.

The cart would have two sets of receivers on it arranged so that each receiver can determine a rough idea of the direction it received the coded IR transmission from.  This could be accomplished, for example, with a few IR detectors in each receiver, with each detector having a narrow reception angle.  The two receivers would be spaced far enough apart so that when the cart got close enough to the person the parallax would be great enough to reliably discern it from inifinite distance.

If the same IR message with the right code isn't received from both receivers at the same time, or there is significant intensity difference between the two, the reception is ignored like it never happened.  The transmitter would send often enough so that missing a few individual receptions causes no real harm.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to clarify if the area is a shopping market or a much bigger airport hall. Not only for the area but also for the lower ceiling and presence of metallic objects (shelves) that could interfere.

One basic technique is to fix a RF emitter to the person/ object (it can emit a short burst every second or so). If you place at least three receivers and can measure the signal strenght with enough accuracy, some basic mathematics will tell you where the source is. Again, this technique works the best in an open space with little electrical perturbations. For different targets, you need different frequencies, and your receiver will also need to be multifrequency.

If you cannot afford a transmitter to be attached to the target for the need of batteries and need a passive transponder, like an RFID tag, then I think (I'm not sure) that the range is very short (a few meters) so you can easily need thousands of them attached to the floor, isn't it a little bit crazy?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure whether its possible even to measure distance along with direction  using RFID tags after surveying for some time,like someone said is it cost effective to use bluetooth or any other technology such as triangulation,etc

Range required is  enough if it is between :2 to 3m but i need identification and detection of point of turn,
i.e:When a person turns in between two shelves the trolley should locate the position of turning and turn precisely without hitting obstacles(even though obstacles can be managed).

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend who tried to make a shopping device for blind people, where the blind person could walk through a shop and be informed about all the products on the shelves by RFID tagging. Unfortunately, however, the RFID equipment only had a range of 20-30 cm, even though the equipment manufacturer claimed it would work for 2-3 meters.